# check if row value is pdf file than display default image

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using the following code to display images from database in grid manner.
This code is working fine and displaying image.but I want to display default image if `row[img]`is "pdf" file. Where i am wrong? Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

```
    <?php
    include("config.inc.php"); //include config file
    //sanitize post value
    $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    //throw HTTP error if page number is not valid
    if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
        exit();
    }

    //get current starting point of records
    $position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);

    //Limit our results within a specified range. 
    $results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT id,name,comment,datetime,img,reply FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");


    //output results from database
$ext=".pdf";


//output results from database


function endsWith($img, $ext){
    $extLength = strlen($ext);
    if(substr($img, -extLength) == $ext){
return true;
    }
   return false;
} 


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{

    //get data
    echo '<article class="white-panel">';



$id = $row['id'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $datetime = $row['datetime'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $img = $row['img'];
If(endsWith($row['img'], ".pdf")){ //executes if return is true        
    echo '<img src="http://myownwebsite.com/image.png" /></a><p>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<img src="http://myownwebiste.com/upload/' .  $row['img'] . '" /></a><p>';
    }
    echo "</article>";
    ?>
```

its my present updated code but not working.

My present code for mutiple selection is as follows as per your update

```
    <?php
    include("config.inc.php"); //include config file
    //sanitize post value
    $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    //throw HTTP error if page number is not valid
    if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
        exit();
    }

    //get current starting point of records
    $position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);

    //Limit our results within a specified range. 
    $results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT id,name,comment,datetime,img,reply FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");


    //output results from database
$ext=".pdf";


//output results from database


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{

    //get data
    echo '<article class="white-panel">';



$id = $row['id'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $datetime = $row['datetime'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $img = $row['img'];

switch(substr($img, -$extLength))
{
  case ".pdf":
echo '<img src="http://myownsite.com/upload/imagepdf.png" /></a><p>';
   break;
  case ".mp4":
echo '<img src="http://myownsite.com/upload/imagemp4.png" /></a><p>';
   break;
default:
echo '<img src="http://myownsite.com/upload/' .  $row['img'] . '" /></a><p>';
   break;
}



echo "</article>";
?>
```

Comment: based on use of `$row['img']` I'm assuming that's just a file name? You could put an if/else statement in that checks if `$row['img']` ends in `.pdf` and then go from there.

Comment: You can find out the file is pdf or not by using the extension. For e.g sample.pdf. Here .pdf is the extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this echecks the last 4 string (.pdf) if it matches it returns true then if executes or else will execute

```
 $ext=".pdf";

function endsWith($img, $ext){
    $extLength = strlen($ext);
    if(substr($img, -$extLength) == $ext){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} 
If(endsWith($row['img'], ".pdf")){ //executes if return is true

echo '<img src="http://example.com/image.png" /></a><p>';
}
else
{   //executes if return is false
echo '<img src="http://example.com/upload/' .  $row['img'] . '" /></a><p>';

}
```

for multiple images for different extension

```
$extLength=4;//most of extensions are 3 character + 1 for '.'
switch(substr($img, -$extLength))
{
  case ".pdf":
   echo "pdf.jpg";
   break;
  case ".mp4":
   echo "mp4.jpg";
   break;

  default://for jpg i.e present
   echo "http://eg.com/$row[img]";
   break;


}
```

Comment: when i put the code it shows default image but unable to execute result if there is already jpg file.

Comment: in substr change extLength as `$extLength`

Comment: If i want to check more than one type like pdf,mp4,mov. and want to show random default images.than what should i do. thanks.

Comment: if you have only one default image then compare all in one if satement like `if(substr($str,-4)==$ext) && substr($str,-4)==$ext)&& ...)

Comment: if you have diffrent images use switch case by defining value for each exetension like 1 for .mp4 2 for jpg ...

Comment: i want to show different images for different file type .can you please give me atleast single example. how to put those switch after one another.

Comment: @ Jasinth , i tried it but not working . what should i do.

Comment: sorry same thing " substr change extLength as `$extLength`"

Comment: @janith premkumar, i posted new code as prescribed by you above which is unfortunately not working.

Comment: try $extlength is null because it is local variable to function so try giving value as number

Comment: can you please exemplify the code as per your suggestions.

Comment: give `$extlength=4` ie(".pdf")

Comment: can you please elaborate more your suggestion by  updating your suggested code (above mentioned) . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Janith, Works like a chram. Thanks for your kind cooperation and patience.

Comment: it is okay brother and it is not janith :)

Comment: sorry Dear. Jasinth Premkumar. Thanks & Good Night

Comment: sweet dreams guddu